# XPath expression to select text WITH link

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I want XPath to return a text with a link embedded in it, can I return both at the same time or am I forced to return:

1. the link & separately
2. the text label of the link

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like below.

```
 //actor[@color='blue']/concat(@id,",",@class)
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide a link to the xpath calculator you are using